# How to set configuration options in pocketsphinx using gstreamer

Tags: python, pocketsphinx, python-gstreamer

Probably a very silly question, but I cannot find a solution anywhere.
When I run 'gst-inspect-1.0 pocketsphinx' I get something like:

```
Current configuration:
[NAME]          [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-agc            none        none
-agcthresh      2.0     2.000000e+00
-allphone               
...

Element Properties:
  name                : The name of the object
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: "pocketsphinx0"
...
```

I know how to set values for the 'element properties', but how do I set values for the other configuration options?  e.g. I'd like to set a value for 'keyphrase' but doing something like

```
asr.set_property("keyphrase", "test")
```

or

```
asr.set_property("-keyphrase", "test")
```

returns

```
TypeError: object of type `GstPocketSphinx' does not have property `keyphrase'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify plugin sources to introduce new properties:

```
g_object_class_install_property
    (gobject_class, PROP_KEYPHRASE,
     g_param_spec_string("keyphrase", "Keyspotting phrase",
                         "Keyspotting phrase",
                         NULL,
                         G_PARAM_READWRITE));

 ....


case PROP_KEYPHRASE:
    gst_pocketsphinx_set_string(ps, "-keyphrase", value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!